# Document set shared metadata not applied to documents in set

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-set, metadata

I have a document set with some custom columns and they are set to be shared to documents in the set, but it doesn't work. Neither when creating new documents from the menu or uploading existing ones.

I had it working for a short while on a test site, but after recreating the setup I can't figure out what I need to do to get it working. Google isn't really helpful as it only talks about some timer event which only seem to be applicable to Sharepoint Server.

Any hints about where to start to figure this one out would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you mean that you set Shared Columns in the document set settings?

Comment: Yes, I set "Shared Columns" option on my Document Set for the applicable columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I managed to solve this myself, the problem seems to have been that I had a Shared Column that had the option "Enforce unique values" set. This seems to break the entire synchronization of  metadata from the Document Set to the individual documents.

Makes sense perhaps but could wish for some better error handling in SP.